# Google Cloud speech API using C++, what is the first step?

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, http2, grpc, google-speech-api

I’m using Google cloud speech API as STT engine in my project which is written in C++ here is  Google Cloud Speech API Documentation. (https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/) It’s available in REST [ non-streaming ] and gRPC lib [ streaming ] .So i’m using gRPC which uses HTTP2 → grpc / grpc.io (http://www.grpc.io/)
Here is the Sample Applicatios  (https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/samples)
main example there are based on [ python - java - node.js - iOS ]

Comment: Your question in the subject is very open-ended and the criteria you provide though specific don't really narrow the issue down.  Are you encountering specific errors, exceptions, etc.?  Given how young this product is, there aren't really any simple examples available using the environment you've specified.  I would suggest reading over the [gRPC Basics for C++](http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/c.html) and trying your hand at applying it to the [Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc/).  Once you encounter specific errors, then we could link into this further.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api) is an example of using the Speech API with C++ with the gRPC transport.